# Finding rows corresponding to an increasing day number

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table that has a numeric column that refers to a day of the week in a pattern.

1 = Monday through to 7 = Sunday.

If the pattern is greater than a week, the numbers continue to increase so 13 would be a Saturday as would 20.

Can anyone help construct a query that finds all numbers relating to a specific day of the week?

Comment: I don't now if I understood the question full, but you can use [modulo](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod) to do this probably. Please edit and specify the question if that doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MOD` to make the number representing weekday circle around back to 1 after hitting 7. The formula is `MOD(weekday-1, 7)+1`

```
select
    weekday
,   mod(weekday-1,7)+1
from test
```

[Demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18253a/1)

Comment: Thank you, just what I was looking for. =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod operator as @dasblinkenlight explained in his answer. To get the names of the day do:

```
select A.weekday, B.day FROM
(select
    weekday,
    mod(weekday-1,7)+1 actualWeekday
from test) A join (
    select 1 weekday, 'MONDAY' day UNION ALL
    select 2 weekday, 'TUESDAY' day UNION ALL
    select 3 weekday, 'WEDNESDAY' day UNION ALL
    select 4 weekday, 'THURSDAY' day UNION ALL
    select 5 weekday, 'FRIDAY' day UNION ALL
    select 6 weekday, 'SATURDAY' day UNION ALL
    select 7 weekday, 'SUNDAY' day
  ) B on A.actualWeekday=B.weekday
order by A.weekday;
```

See [**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18253a/8)